# Method to get the placement of a player with SQL Query

Tags: java, mysql, sql, eclipse-plugin, minecraft

I want to create a BuildFFA plugin. This plugin contains a Statistic-System. I want to create a method which calculate your placement.

```
public static int ranking(UUID uuid) {
        try (PreparedStatement ps = MySQL.getConnection().prepareStatement("SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Kills DESC) pos FROM kills WHERE UUID = ?")){
            ps.setString(1, uuid.toString());
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery(); 
            if(rs.next()) {
                return rs.getRow();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

Problem:
If the database contains the player it always return 1.
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `rs.getInt('<columnName>')` instead of `rs.getRow()`